# EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) for App Review Team. Not Reproducible

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, crash-reports

So, my App (iOS, Swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3) got rejected by Beta App Review team because it crahsed on launch.

**UPDATE** Got an answer from the App Review Team...it's only crashing on iPad, not on iPhone.

The thing is that I can't reproduce this crash. Not even when testing on my 3 physical devices (iPhone 4S, iPhone6 and iPad Air) with a clean install nor update through TestFlight Internal Testing (so exactly the same build & archive as App Review Team is reviewing)

Extract of crash log (received from App Review Team) (symbolicated):

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010032ced8
Triggered by Thread:  0
Filtered syslog:
None found
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   AppName                       0x000000010032ced8 MapViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (MapViewController.swift:210)
1   AppName                       0x000000010032cf2c @objc MapViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (MapViewController.swift:0)
2   UIKit                         0x0000000187394b40 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
```

MapViewController is the rootViewController of the UINavigationController and line 210 contains: `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()`

**UPDATE**:
Removed that line and submitted another build. Same crash log, now crashing on the next line: `imageview.hidden = true`

Tried to run in "Release" config directly from Xcode on my Device, in the hope it would crash and point me in the right direction, however, no crash :-/
Also, very interesting, I had the same in a previous build of the same app (also got rejected). I sent the review team a reply similar to this story and they approved it for external beta testing (without any changes). Only one of my beta testers (aprox 300 total) reported a similar crash on startup.

Did a lot of googling on the Sigtrap breakpoint, but haven't found anything similar to what I'm experiencing. So, I'm really at a loss here. I can't reproduce it and the the crash log doesn't point me in any direction I could investigate.

**UPDATE:** Here is the complete (symbolicated) crash report I got from the App Review Team. (excl. Binary Images, all looked fine there). Perhaps something in there (other threads perhaps?) rings a bell for someone. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Incident Identifier: 5A47A678-EDD0-400B-873F-4BF466E13218
CrashReporter Key:   31c74ad5c3da4b8205dc32464f9bc6fde2f4edea
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             AppName [2081]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/065CA51D-8981-419B-BEB8-3BD5255073E8/AppName.app/AppName
Identifier:          com.pinguido.scenic
Version:             1 (1.08)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-05-06 20:56:49.49 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-05-06 20:56:49.49 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.1 (13E238)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010032d7fc
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   AppName                         0x000000010032d7fc MapViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (MapViewController.swift:216)
1   AppName                         0x000000010032d850 @objc MapViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (MapViewController.swift:0)
2   UIKit                           0x0000000187520b40 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
3   UIKit                           0x00000001875e1118 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 72
4   UIKit                           0x00000001875e0ff0 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 416
5   UIKit                           0x00000001875e0238 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 144
6   UIKit                           0x00000001875dfddc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 868
7   UIKit                           0x00000001875dfa04 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60
8   UIKit                           0x00000001875df96c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208
9   UIKit                           0x000000018751c0e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
10  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184ec2a28 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
11  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184ebd634 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
12  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184ebd4f4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
13  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184ebcb24 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
14  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184ebc86c CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
15  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184eb5dd8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001823947b0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182392554 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822bcd30 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 416
19  UIKit                           0x000000018758f834 -[UIApplication _run] + 460
20  UIKit                           0x0000000187589f70 UIApplicationMain + 204
21  AppName                         0x000000010042be50 main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000181e5a8b8 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f78b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f794d8 kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181e3c7d8 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181e2b648 _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f78b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f78b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f7841c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181e9522c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181e9514c usleep + 68
3   AppName                         0x000000010086ac48 recvTimeout + 196
4   AppName                         0x000000010086f864 ConnectionWrapper::recv() + 192
5   AppName                         0x000000010086fed4 HttpUtils::readHttpStatusLine(ConnectionWrapper&, unsigned short&) + 68
6   AppName                         0x000000010086de90 skobbler::HTTP::HttpRequest::receiveAnswerImpl(bool) + 64
7   AppName                         0x000000010086d878 skobbler::HTTP::HttpRequest::receiveAnswer(bool) + 44
8   AppName                         0x000000010086c4ec skobbler::HTTP::HttpManager::HttpWorkerThread::processRequest() + 88
9   AppName                         0x000000010086c938 skobbler::HTTP::HttpManager::HttpWorkerThread::runHelper(void*) + 48
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f77f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182042ce8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   AppName                         0x000000010080b7ec RouteManager::run() + 2588
3   AppName                         0x0000000100807d74 RouteManager::runHelper(void*) + 12
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f7841c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181e9522c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181e9514c usleep + 68
3   AppName                         0x000000010086ac48 recvTimeout + 196
4   AppName                         0x000000010086f864 ConnectionWrapper::recv() + 192
5   AppName                         0x000000010086fed4 HttpUtils::readHttpStatusLine(ConnectionWrapper&, unsigned short&) + 68
6   AppName                         0x000000010086de90 skobbler::HTTP::HttpRequest::receiveAnswerImpl(bool) + 64
7   AppName                         0x000000010086d878 skobbler::HTTP::HttpRequest::receiveAnswer(bool) + 44
8   AppName                         0x000000010086c4ec skobbler::HTTP::HttpManager::HttpWorkerThread::processRequest() + 88
9   AppName                         0x000000010086c938 skobbler::HTTP::HttpManager::HttpWorkerThread::runHelper(void*) + 48
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f77f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182042d20 _pthread_cond_wait + 704
2   AppName                         0x00000001007b64e4 SkTimer<MapMatcher, &(MapMatcher::positioningRoutineWrapper(MapMatcher*))>::entryPoint(void*) + 120
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f77f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182042ce8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   AppName                         0x00000001006d1354 ThreadWorker::run() + 72
3   AppName                         0x000000010080107c RunInThread::runHelper(void*) + 28
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f77f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182042ce8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   AppName                         0x0000000100622cf0 TileLoader<MapRenderer>::run() + 2512
3   AppName                         0x0000000100770974 TileLoader<MapRenderer>::runHelper(void*) + 12
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f77f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182042d20 _pthread_cond_wait + 704
2   AppName                         0x00000001007748c4 SkTimer<ReRenderTimer, &(ReRenderTimer::reRenderRoutine(ReRenderTimer*))>::entryPoint(void*) + 120
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f77f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182042d20 _pthread_cond_wait + 704
2   AppName                         0x00000001007747f0 SkTimer<AnimationTimer, &(AnimationTimer::animationTimerRoutine(AnimationTimer*))>::entryPoint(void*) + 120
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f77f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182042ce8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   AppName                         0x00000001006a46c4 WorldTextures::WorkerThreadRoutine(void*) + 100
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f77f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182042ce8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   AppName                         0x00000001006aa2ac EarthSphere::WorkerThreadRoutine(void*) + 120
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f77f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182042ce8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2   AppName                         0x00000001006e2fdc MapSearch::runLoop(void*) + 128
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f77f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182042d20 _pthread_cond_wait + 704
2   AppName                         0x000000010077fa34 SkTimer<FcdCollector, &(FcdCollector::timerRoutineWrapper(FcdCollector*))>::entryPoint(void*) + 120
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f7841c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181e9522c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181efe09c sleep + 44
3   AppName                         0x00000001008010a4 TimerTarget::run() + 20
4   AppName                         0x000000010080107c RunInThread::runHelper(void*) + 28
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043b28 _pthread_body + 156
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182043a8c _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041028 thread_start + 4

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f78b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181f78b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182041020 start_wqthread + 4
```

**EDIT**
As some people asked in the comments, here is the code from my AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and my rootVC's `viewDidLoad` As I mentioned, I don't think it's anything in my viewDidLoad as it always crashes on the first line of the viewDidLoad. I'm guessing it's something in my AppDel or perhaps something global... i.e. something that is executed before my rootVC's viewDidLoad.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    print("APPDEL: applicationDidFinishLaunching")
    appWasCompletelyClosed = true

    // Set SKMaps API Key & Light Map
    let initSettings: SKMapsInitSettings = SKMapsInitSettings()
    initSettings.mapDetailLevel = SKMapDetailLevel.Light
    initSettings.showConsoleLogs = false
    SKMapsService.sharedInstance().initializeSKMapsWithAPIKey(SKMapsAPIKey, settings: initSettings)

    if UD.appVersion == nil || UD.appVersion != "\(NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"]!)" {
        startClean()
        UD.appVersion = "\(NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"]!)"
    }

    // Get IAP Products & Prices
    IAPHelper.sharedInstance.requestProducts(){(success) -> Void in
        if !success {
            printError("Error getting IAP Products")
        }
    }

    if UD.userID == nil {
        print("First Launch")
        copyCleanDBtoApplicationsFolder()
        MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed("scenic.sqlite")
        LastSync.resetAll()
        firstLaunch = true
        UD.userID = NSUUID().UUIDString
        print(UD.userID)
        let newUser = User.MR_createEntity()
        newUser.id = UD.userID
        newUser.addedOn = NSDate()
        newUser.lastChanged = NSDate()
        newUser.points = 0
        newUser.pointsToNextLevel = 5
        newUser.level = 0
        newUser.rankWorld = 0
        newUser.rankCountry = 0

        #if DEBUG
            newUser.offlineMapCredits = 100
        #else
            newUser.offlineMapCredits = 5
        #endif


        saveContext()
        self.setUserDefaultsForFirstTime()
        self.createSubDirs()
        Sync.user() {(error) -> Void in
            if error {
                print("There was an error creating the new user on the server. Will try again before next sync action.")
            }
            else {
                print("User succesfully created on the server.")
                UD.userUploadedFirstTime = true
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed("scenic.sqlite")
    }


    // Initialize cache with offline map regions
    SKMapsService.sharedInstance().mapsVersioningManager.delegate = self
    SKTDownloadManager.sharedInstance()
    //cachedMapRegions = Array<MapRegion>()

    // Set Map to Offline if "Get Map Data Online" is set to No
    setMapConnectivityMode()


    if TripLogger.sharedInstance.logFileExists() {
        appClosedDuringTrip = true
    }

    print("APPDEL: end of applicationDidFinishLaunching")
    return true
}
```

viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("MAPVC: viewDidLoad")
    //self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()




    // UI Stuff
    profilePicImageView.hidden = true
    profilePicShadowView.hidden = true
    profilePicImageViewTopConstraint.constant -= 30
    profilePicShadowViewTopConstraint.constant -= 30

    searchBar.hidden = true
    searchBarTopConstraint.constant -= 30

    settingsButton.hidden = true
    settingsButtonTopConstraint.constant -= 30

    centerOnCurrentLocationButton.hidden = true
    centerOnCurrentLocationButtonLeadingConstraint.constant -= 30

    locationsButton.hidden = true
    locationsButtonLeadingConstraint.constant -= 30

    startButton.hidden = true
    startButtonBottomConstraint.constant -= 30

    routesButton.hidden = true
    routesButtonTrailingConstraint.constant -= 30

    locationsMenuWidth.constant = 0
    locationsMenuHeight.constant = 0
    routesMenuWidth.constant = 0
    routesMenuHeight.constant = 0
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


    routesMenu.hidden = true
    locationsMenu.hidden = true

    centerOnCurrentLocationButtonIsHidden = centerOnCurrentLocationButton.hidden

    navInfoView.hidden = true
    searchResultsTableView.hidden = true
    cancelSearchButton.hidden = true

    profileTableView.hidden = true
    profileTableView.layer.cornerRadius = theme.cornerRadius

    profileTableView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    profileTableView.backgroundColor = theme.buttonBackgroundColor

    profileTableView.clipsToBounds = true

    searchResultsTableView.hidden = true
    searchResultsTableView.layer.cornerRadius = theme.cornerRadius

    searchResultsTableView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = theme.buttonBackgroundColor
    searchResultsTableView.clipsToBounds = true

    // ForceTouchRecognizer
    let forceTouches: Array<DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer> = [forceTouchRoutesButton, forceTouchLocationsButton]
    for f in forceTouches {
        f.timeout = 0.5
        f.forceTouchDelay = 0.3
        f.baseForceTouchPressure = 3.0
        f.triggeringForceTouchPressure = 6.0
        f.delegate = self
    }



    locationsButton.addGestureRecognizer(forceTouchLocationsButton)
    routesButton.addGestureRecognizer(forceTouchRoutesButton)


    // Search Bar
    HNKGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery.setupSharedQueryWithAPIKey(GooglePlacesAPIKey)
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchResultsTableView.delegate = self
    searchResultsTableView.dataSource = self
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: .Any, barMetrics: .Default)
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    // Vehicle TableViewSlider
    vehiclesImageSliderView = PRSlideView()
    vehiclesImageSliderView.delegate = self
    vehiclesImageSliderView.dataSource = self
    vehiclesImageSliderView.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
    vehiclesImageSliderView.infiniteScrollingEnabled = false
    vehiclesImageSliderView.registerClass(
        PRAlbumPage.self,
        identifier: PRAlbumPage.description()
    )


    // Browse Routes
    routesInMapAreaView.hidden = true
    filterView.hidden = true
    configureFilters()


    // Profile TableView
    tvc = UITableViewController()
    tvc.tableView = self.profileTableView
    profileTableView.delegate = self
    profileTableView.dataSource = self
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.frameHeight = 40
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("Last update: %@",comment:"Refreshcontrol subtitle"),LastSync.users.timeAgoSinceNowOrNever()), attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:theme.textColor])
    weak var weakSelf: MapViewController? = self
    refreshControl.addTarget(weakSelf, action: #selector(MapViewController.tableRefresh), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    tvc.refreshControl = refreshControl

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate
    if appDelegate.appWasCompletelyClosed && UD.mapUnfolding! {
        foldMapOpen()
    }
    else {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
            self.locManager = CLLocationManager()
            self.locManager.delegate = self
            self.locManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.initializeAndAnimateMap(false)
            }
        default:
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.initializeAndAnimateMap(true)
            }
        }
    }

    let subMenuButtons: Array<UIButton> = [favoriteRoutesButton, createRouteButton, importRoutesButton, showRoutesButton, favoriteLocationsButton, createLocationButton, importLocationButton]
    for subMenuButton in subMenuButtons {
        subMenuButton.setLayerProperties(backgroundColor: UIColor.clearColor(), opacity: nil, cornerRadius: 12, borderColor: theme.tintColor, borderWidth: theme.borderWidth, shadowOffset: nil)
    }
    myTripsButton.setLayerProperties(backgroundColor: UIColor.clearColor(), opacity: nil, cornerRadius: 12, borderColor: theme.okGreenColor, borderWidth: theme.borderWidth, shadowOffset: nil)


    let closeButtons: Array<UIButton> = [closeNavInfoButton, closeRoutesInMapAreaButton, closeFilterViewButton]
    for button in closeButtons {
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        button.setTitle("✕", forState: .Normal)
        button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 14)
        button.backgroundColor = theme.tintColor
    }

    routeAvoidanceSelector = WLHorizontalSegmentedControl(items: ["avoid Tolls","avoid Highway","avoid Ferries"])
    routeAvoidanceSelector.allowsMultiSelection = true
    routeAvoidanceSelector.addTarget(weakSelf, action: #selector(MapViewController.routeAvoidanceChanged), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    let segControlFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11, weight: UIFontWeightMedium)
    let attr = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: (NSFontAttributeName, segControlFont))
    routeModeSelector.setTitleTextAttributes(attr, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    routeModeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = UD.routeMode!.rawValue
    vehicleTypeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = UD.vehicleType!.rawValue
    setSelectedRouteAvoidances()
    routeAvoidanceSelector.tintColor = theme.tintColor
    guidanceToStartSwitch.setOn(UD.guideToStart!, animated: false)
    navInfoView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    vehicleTypeImageView.roundCorners(UIRectCorner.BottomRight, radius: theme.textViewCornerRadius)
    vehicleTypeImageView.roundCorners([UIRectCorner.TopLeft,UIRectCorner.BottomRight], radius: theme.textViewCornerRadius)
    vehicleTypeImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(MapViewController.resigningActive),
        name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification,
        object: nil
    )
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(MapViewController.becomeActive),
        name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
        object: nil
    )

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(MapViewController.deviceRotated),
        name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification,
        object: nil
    )

}
```

Comment: I'd venture to guess that the app review team have testing software which we don't have access to?  Did they tell you under what circumstances this occurred?

Comment: They said it "crashed on launch". One strange this is that the "Hardware-model" in their crash reports is xxx, while normally it's something like iPhone7,2 or iPad 4,2 etc. I'm guessing they probably have some kind of automated test setup which runs the app on multiple devices (or simulators???) at once. I asked them what the xxx stands for... no response yet.

Comment: Your Segment says line 210, but the apple crash log says 216. What is on both of those?

Comment: Sorry Siriss. The crash report extract above was from the initial build I submitted. On line 210 is self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor() the full crash log is from the 2nd build (where I deleted 210) and then it crashed on the next line (216) where it says image view.hidden = true. In both cases it was the very first line of viewDidLoad. This makes me think it's not something in that viewcontroller, but perhaps somewhere else (App delegate or global)

Comment: @Guido : Have u used any global parent view controller means all other view controller inherits directly from that class. So you defined common methods and functions into that.

Comment: we need to show snaps of your didfinishlaunchingwithoptions methods of app delegate as well as Starting initials view controller

Comment: or you can install iOS Console and get better crash report exactly what happened

Comment: @Pavan... No parent vc (other than ViewController) MapViewController is the root vc of my navigation vc. Will post appdelegate didfinishwithlaunching tomorrow (on iPhone now)

Comment: Never heard of iConsole until now. Will give it a try!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111367/discussion-between-pavan-and-guido).

Comment: just defined here the viewdidload of your root controller, and appdelegate launching methods.

Comment: SIGTRAP is an exception not an error. (eg, array out of bound, or assigning nil to non-optional var in swift). So the issue can be in the Map framework instead of main thread, due to some configuration error. Have you tried to debug using release configuration, or ad-hoc build.

Comment: Guido, can you post the MapViewController.viewDidLoad() code? The crash part

Comment: @RJE, Yes tried in release config. No crash. Also tried enabling all exceptions in debugger, but no exceptions thrown when running on my devices. (Tried this also in debug and config)

Comment: As requested, Ive added my viewDidLoad and applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: OK. Got an answer from the App Review Team...it's only crashing on iPad for them. Updated my question with this info.

Comment: Check if the viewDidLoad is being called in a background thread somehow. You may be calling UI elements in the background because of various timers, animations, delegates, etc..

Comment: @frankish. I checked my code for that, but can't seem to find anything. Using storyboard, and this is the rootVC of my UINavController (which is the initial controller) so viewDidLoad is 'automatically' called (not from code) on app start.

Comment: Looks like there's nothing you can do... http://jmduke.com/posts/all-new-app-store-apps-with-embedded-frameworks-are-broken/

Comment: @RJE... it was your comment that made me double check if I was forcefully unwrapping an optional. If you want the bounty, post an answer and I'll assign it to you! Thanks!

Comment: Next build was rejected again. Made some radical changes and it got approved. Check my update in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Haha,

*--@RJE... it was your comment that made me double check if I was forcefully unwrapping an optional. If you want the bounty, post an answer and I'll assign it to you! Thanks! – guido 5 hours ago"--*

Bounties are always important,

Anyway it is very important to know that what is **SIGTRAP** means. It is basically a run-time exception not an error. So if you cannot really find the issue you have to check that if there are any places which can course an exception. (specially with Swift optional types)

Usually it can be array index out of bound or unwrapping nil or any thing similar. Also if it only occurs sometimes or only on some device there is a possibility of a issue due to various delays of UI animations.(e.g. presentViewController withAnimation and trying some thing before its completion.)

But honestly I don't see any issue with your original code. It shouldn't have crashed.

Unless if Storyboard's initial point is a UINavigationController and you forgot to set its class as a *CustomNavigationController*. Then it will crash at below code. (this is expected in Swift).

```
let navController = window!.rootViewController as! CustomNavigationController
```

But I don't think that this is the issue. Coz it should have crashed every time on any device.

And also by the time *applicationDidBecomeActive* called window wont be nil. So it can be some thing else you are doing with navController after this point.

Or may be Apple's review team tested your app on a faulty device :)

Comment: Hi. So have you found any solution or anything else, I have same issue and apple has rejected my app.

Answer (score 2):

I got it approved.

---

**UPDATE**

While I got it approved, the next build of the app was rejected again, same reason, same sort of crash reports, again pointing to the first line of the viewDidLoad method.

I then radically threw all my code from viewDidLoad into viewWillAppear like this:

```
var viewLoaded = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do nothing
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if !viewLoaded {

        // viewDidLoad code

        viewLoaded = true
    }

    // viewWillAppear code

}
```

My theory now is that I discovered an Apple Bug:

I'm using storyboards and my rootViewController is very (very) heavy. Lots of UIVIews, UILabels, MapView, Buttons, Searcher, Embedded TableView etc. My guess is that it crashed because not all storyboard elements were initialised when viewDidLoad was called.

If this is indeed true (time will tell when I submit more builds for review) I think I either discovered a bug in iOS (as I should be able to reference IBOutlets from the storyboard in my viewDidLoad) or a discrepancy in the review process running the app, compared to actual devices running the app (as neither me nor any of my 400 beta testers is experiencing this crash).

**END OF UPDATE**

---

Based on RJE's comment I took another look at my AppDelegate to see if I was forcefully unwrapping something. I was, but to my knowledge these values could never be nil so I didn't give it another thought when I first coded it. I guess I should have.

In the build that finally got approved 3 things were different from the previous one that didn't get approved.

1. In my AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I was forcefully unwrapping `NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"]!`

I changed

```
if UD.appVersion == nil || UD.appVersion != "\(NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"]!)" {
    startClean()
    UD.appVersion = "\(NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"]!)"
}
```

to this

```
var versionInInfoDictionary = "dummy"
if let infoDict = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary {
    if let bundleVersion = infoDict["CFBundleVersion"] as? String{
        versionInInfoDictionary = bundleVersion
    }
    else {
        printError("bundleVersion nil")
    }
}
else {
    printError("infoDic nil")
}

if UD.appVersion == nil || UD.appVersion != versionInInfoDictionary {
    startClean()
    UD.appVersion = versionInInfoDictionary
}
```

2. In my AppDelegate `applicationDidBecomeActive` I was forcefully unwrapping `window` (defined in my AppDelegate class as `var window: UIWindow?` )

I changed

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    // some code

    let navController = window!.rootViewController as! CustomNavigationController

    // some code
}
```

to this

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    // some code
    self.continueDidBecomeActive()
}

func continueDidBecomeActive() {
    guard window != nil else {
        printError("Window still nil")
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.continueDidBecomeActive), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        return
    }
    if let navController = window!.rootViewController as? CustomNavigationController {

        // some code

    }
}
```

3. And Finally in my build settings I had the Code Signing Identity for 'Release' set to iOS Developer. I changed that to iOS Distribution.

Now, I don't think it was the 3rd point that made my app crash for the App Review Team, otherwise it would have crashed on all devices and also for me.

So, it has to be either number 1, number 2 or both. Honestly I don't know and I'm still a bit confused as to why these values would be nil in any circumstance. If there are any more insights... I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Did you find your theory of ViewDidLoad called prior to view is ready true? I mean storyboard code should be call during loadView which should guarantee to happen before viewDidLoad right? they are happen on mainthread which is serial

Comment: No proof. I solved it in a different way and decided not to dive into the Apple radar rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. No crashes on my test devices but Apple said they weren't able to start the App.

I messaged the review team in the resolution center. They started the review process again and couldn't reproduce crashes. Finally my App got accepted :)